# Who stabbed Frodo?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

In *The Lord of the Rings* there are five Nazgûl that remain behind and attack the Hobbits on Weathertop.

Which Nagûl stabbed Frodo? Was it the Witch-king or was he one of the four that pursued Gandalf?

***Crown as evidence***:

While the answers are good and point to it being the Witch-king, the question [Who were the Nazgul before they became wraiths?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22949/who-were-the-nazgul-before-they-became-wraiths) refers to ***kings*** plural therefore wearing a crown is only a pointer and not definitive. I'll wait to see if more evidence becomes available.

Comment: It is true that the Nazgûl are said to have been kings. However only the one who stabbed Frodo is described as wearing a crown at the time of the attack. It's possible that Tolkien neglected to mention the crowns on the heads of the others, but I think it more likely that it was only the leader of the Nazgûl (the Witch-King) who still wore a crown.

Comment: "The one who will lead Sauron's armies in war, The Witch King of Angmar, you have met him before... he stabbed Frodo on Weathertop."

Comment: @jacksonecac movie quote? That scene differs from the books as all nine attack

Comment: Maggie! Wait, sorry, that’s who shot Mr. Burns. (Spoilers.)

Comment: Well, whoever he was, he was a real jerk :(

Answer (score 74):

### It was the Witch-King who stabs Frodo.

> There were five tall figures: two standing on the lip of the dell,
>   three advancing. In their white faces burned keen and merciless eyes; under their mantles were long grey robes; **upon their grey hairs were helms of silver**;... Two of the figures halted. **The third was taller than**
>   **the others: his hair was long and gleaming and on his helm was a**
>   **crown.** In one hand he held a long sword, and in the other a **knife**;
>   both the knife and the hand that held it glowed with a pale light. **He**
>   **sprang forward and bore down on Frodo**.
>
> At that moment Frodo threw himself forward on the ground, and he heard
>   himself crying aloud: O Elbereth! Gilthoniel! At the same time he
>   struck at the feet of his enemy. A shrill cry rang out in the night;
>   and he felt a pain like a dart of poisoned ice pierce his left
>   shoulder.
>
> *Tolkien, J.R.R.. The Fellowship of the Ring: Being the First Part of*
>   *The Lord of the Rings (pp. 195-196). Houghton Mifflin Harcourt. Kindle*
>   *Edition.*

---

> but all blades perish that pierce that **dreadful King**. -Aragorn to Frodo about the incident.

The other four all had silver helms, only one of the five had a crown on top.

> For even the Wise might fear to withstand the Nine, when they are gathered together under their fell chieftain. A **great king** and sorcerer he was of old, and now he wields a deadly fear. -Gandalf on the nine.

Comment: It's weird that they don't *all* have crowns, given they were all kings...

Comment: @Medinoc i assume the silver helms were their "battle crowns" fancy headwear, and being the head/king of kings the additional crown on top is what distinguished the witch king

Comment: @Medinoc they weren't defo all kings

Answer (score 28):

If you're ok with taking the movies' word for it, Gandalf clearly states that it was the Witch-king

> **Gandalf:** *Sauron has yet to reveal his deadliest servant. The one who would lead Mordor's armies in war. The one they say no living man can kill: the Witch-King of Angmar. You've met him before. **He stabbed Frodo on Weathertop**.*

Answer (score 27):

### It was the Witch-King (Probably)

> *Two of the figures halted. **The third was taller than the others: his
> hair was long and gleaming and on his helm was a crown.** In one hand
> he held a long sword, and in the other a knife; both the knife and the
> hand that held it glowed with a pale light. **He sprang forward and
> bore down on Frodo.***
>
> *At that moment Frodo threw himself forward on the ground, and he heard
> himself crying aloud: O Elbereth! Gilthoniel! At the same time he
> struck at the feet of his enemy. **A shrill cry rang out in the night;
> and he felt a pain like a dart of poisoned ice pierce his left
> shoulder.***

Theoretically it could have been from another of the Nazgûl (we don't see the actual strike) but the implication is very clear.

---

In the [Peter Jackson film adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings:_The_Fellowship_of_the_Ring), the event is rather clearer

> **IN THE TWILIGHT WORLD:**
>
> *Frodo finds himself in the weird twilight world...he looks upon the
> Ringwraiths, now visible in their TRUE APPEARANCE: Five Ghouls dressed
> in long Grey robes, with white hair, and Pallid, ruthless faces. THE
> WITCH KING extends a haggard hand towards Frodo, reaching for the ring
> on his finger. Frodo's trembling hand extends forward as if by the
> pull of the ring...he slides to the ground, unable to pull his hand
> away. **The witch king snarls and springs forward. He stabs at Frodo
> with a wicked dagger! Frodo winces as the tip of the dagger sinks into
> his shoulder.** Suddenly, Strider charges at the RINGWRAITHS, wielding
> his sword in one hand, a flaming torch in the other. He moves in slow
> motion, visible through a sea of mist. Frodo sinks to the ground.
> Behind him is a faint image of a Ringwraith fleeing, his head engulfed
> in flames. With draining strength, Frodo manages to pull the ring off
> his finger...*
>
> <sub><sup>[LOTR: Fellowship of the Ring - Original Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Lord-of-the-Rings-Fellowship-of-the-Ring,-The.html)</sup></sub>

[image]

---

And again in the [Ralph Bakshi adaptation of Lord of the Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_(1978_film)), he's quite definitely stabbed by a character later identified as the Witch-King.

[image]

Comment: Does the crown indicate he's the witch king though, as other nazgûl are described as great kings of men

Comment: @Po-ta-toe - The tallness is the giveaway. He's the leader.

Comment: He's the tallest of the five.

Comment: That  Ralph Bakshi - looks very much to me like live film (someone filmed in green light wearing a practical suit) with traditional animation added in.

Comment: @Tim - For $500, Alex. What is "[Rotoscoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping)"?

Comment: yeah, I went and looked up the making of the film.  Though I think in that gif the king isn't entirely rotoscoped; some of the real actor was allowed to be shown.  Probably as a budget saver.

Comment: @Tim - Bakshi's film is the far superior of the adaptations. I heartily recommend it.

Comment: I'll certainly check it out.  But superior?  As a native kiwi that will be my judgement to make :-P

Comment: @Tim - Pfft. If you've seen one mountain, you've seen 'em all. If you remove the long helicopter shots and over-extended fight sequences, Jackson's films are about four minutes long each.

Answer (score 12):

It was the lord of the Nazgûl (previously known as the Witch King of Angmar), or at least it seems to have been the most powerful black rider present.

> Two of the figures halted. The third was taller than the others: his hair was long and gleaming and on his helm was a crown. In one hand he held a long sword, and in the other a knife; both the knife and the hand that held it glowed with a pale light. He sprang forward and bore down on Frodo.

Tolkien seemed to have a thing about height as a indicator of power.  (Eomer was the tallest of the riders who accosted Aragorn, Legolas, and Gimli.)  The way the figure with the blade is singled out strongly suggests it was Nazgûl lord.